# 'matlab.object' object is not callable using matlab engine

Tags: python, matlab, simulink, matlab-compiler, matlab-engine

I am trying to use MATLAB engine from Python as follows

```
sinewave = eng.dsp.SineWave("Amplitude",1,"Frequency",fc,"SampleRate",fs,"SamplesPerFrame",nspf,"ComplexOutput",True)
sinewave()
```

to use the DSP toolbox. However, I get the error "`'matlab.object' object is not callable` for sinewave()".
Doing the same, directly in MATLAB (without the `eng.`) works just fine. What is the correct way for calling sinewave from Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok got it.

For anyone that's looking, once you get your object, add it to your workspace and then call the workspace variable using `eval`. In this case, this would be

```
sinewave = eng.dsp.SineWave("Amplitude",1,"Frequency",fc,"SampleRate",fs,"SamplesPerFrame",nspf,"ComplexOutput",True)
eng.workspace['sinewave'] = sinewave
x = eng.eval('sinewave()')
```

And then since in MATLAB, my x would have been a vector, in Python, my x is a Python list and I can print the first element using x[0] or whatever I want to do. I can also add x into the workspace and keep working like that.