# Calling created MATLAB object from Python when using matlabengine library

Tags: python, function, matlab, calling-convention

I'm trying to call an instance of MATLAB's scatteredInterpolant object from Python. For example, interpolating two points with given values in MATLAB from a Python code can be done as follows:

```
import matlab.engine
eng=matlab.engine.start_matlab()
a=matlab.double([[1,2],[4,5]])
b=eng.scatteredInterpolant(a,matlab.double([[1],[2]]),'linear')
```

However, when I go to call `b`, I run into errors:

```
c=eng.b(matlab.double([1,2]))
Unrecognized function or variable 'b'.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MatlabExecutionError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 1
----> 1 c=eng.b(matlab.double([1,2]))

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matlab/engine/matlabengine.py:71, in MatlabFunc.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     68     return FutureResult(self._engine(), future, nargs, _stdout, _stderr, feval=True)
     69 else:
     70     return FutureResult(self._engine(), future, nargs, _stdout,
---> 71                         _stderr, feval=True).result()

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matlab/engine/futureresult.py:67, in FutureResult.result(self, timeout)
     64     if timeout < 0:
     65         raise TypeError(pythonengine.getMessage('TimeoutCannotBeNegative'))
---> 67 return self.__future.result(timeout)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matlab/engine/fevalfuture.py:82, in FevalFuture.result(self, timeout)
     79 if not result_ready:
     80     raise TimeoutError(pythonengine.getMessage('MatlabFunctionTimeout'))
---> 82 self._result = pythonengine.getFEvalResult(self._future,self._nargout, None, out=self._out, err=self._err)
     83 self._retrieved = True
     84 return self._result

MatlabExecutionError: Undefined function 'b' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

or

```
c=b(matlab.double([1,2]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 1
----> 1 c=b(matlab.double([1,2]))

TypeError: 'matlab.object' object is not callable
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try `c=b(…)`? You declared `b` in the previous line, not `eng.b`.  `b` is a Python variable that references the MATLAB object.

Comment: Yes, that's my second code snippet in the question - or did you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that. Maybe try `eng.feval(b,matlab.double([1,2]))`?

Comment: Yep, throws the error ``Error using feval
Function to evaluate must be represented as a string scalar, character vector, or function_handle object.``

Comment: Then what is `b`? The documentation says "Interpolating function that you can evaluate at query points." But this last error message says it's not a function. I guess it's an object with the `()` indexing overloaded to do interpolation? Can you do `b[[1,2]]` or `b[matlab.double([1,2])]`? (I don't have the Python bindings installed here, so can't try this out myself.)

Comment: ``b`` is just a ``matlab.object``, and neither of your suggestions work.

Comment: That is frustrating! I guess this is a gap in the Python bindings. Found another Q&A with the same answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74045483/7328782

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

Turns out MATLAB objects created in Python need to be sent over to the MATLAB engine manually. So, the following code snippet works:

```
import matlab.engine
eng=matlab.engine.start_matlab()
a=matlab.double([[1,2],[4,5]])
b=eng.scatteredInterpolant(a,matlab.double([[1],[2]]),'linear')
new_points = matlab.double([[2, 3], [5, 6]])
eng.workspace['new_points']=new_points
eng.workspace['b'] = b
result=eng.eval('b(new_points)')
```

Comment: This seems like a usable workaround, but using `eval` is always less than ideal. There must be a better way of doing this.